# Can I use array modifiers to create staggered rows of blocks in a dome?

Tags: modifiers

I have built up a number of courses of blocks on a dome I'm building using array modifiers and NURBS circles. It works pretty well but each row of blocks starts at the same place, so the first several blocks are lined up on top of each other. That isn't how a real dome would be made and I'd like to fix it.

I haven't found a way to rotate the circles so the blocks rotate too without them spiraling outwards. How should I set this up?[image]

Edit: I have set up the arrays as recommended in the linked answers from the comments [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23664/7548) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28768/7548). However, this technique won't work for a **dome**. Successive rows of blocks need to be smaller along a curve, and this technique only allows linear scaling. I have been trying adding a deform modifier to the stack, but so far haven't found one that will create a dome without severely deforming the blocks. I am about to try the add-on recommended in sambler's answer, but it may not allow me to use the rounded blocks that would be correct.

The building technique being imitated is shown below. Usually the dome shape used is a beehive style, I couldn't find an illustration of a spherical dome.

[image: earthbag dome]

Comment: Check this answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28765/a-reliable-way-to-make-a-brick-tower

Comment: @Denis That looks great, but it doesn't make successive rows smaller. Can it be adapted to do that?

Comment: You can have multiple arrays and use the empty to adjust the scale

Comment: You could use 2 arrays and add **Simple Deform** modifier atop of them set to *Taper*. Adjusting its *Factor* you'll be able to create expanded/tapered forms

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23664/1853

Comment: Is this the type of result you want?: http://fireworksmasonry.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Phillipsburg-NJ-Dome-Wood-Fired-Backyard-Bread-Oven-3760.jpg

Comment: @RegusMartin since you asked, i'm building an Earthbag-type dome on the Moon. :-| ..so, not really.

Comment: @kimholder Thanks for adding an image! I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @RegusMartin - oh cool - it hadn't occurred to me that that was why you were asking. :P Though i should say, since i need to move forward i have been building the dome row by row. I got a set of circles scaled correctly to be the curves for each row by taking the rings from an iconosphere and converting them to curves. Now i'm copying the block > switching the object of the curve modifier to the right circle > moving it up to the right height, and a bit to the side to rotate it (it stays aligned with the circle still, if the array modifier is set to fixed count).

Comment: @kimholder I tried my ideas. None worked without visible distortion. Looks like you will have to do it the manual way. Funny, I thought this would be easy. :P

Comment: @RegusMartin Tell me about it. I guess it is one of those unusual applications where it has never been worth creating shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

There is an addon called Building Objects available in blenders [addon contrib](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/) collection that may come close to what you want. With it enabled you get *Add->Mesh->Building Objects->Wall factory* to create a wall made of bricks.

While the radial and curve options will give you an igloo like brickwork it doesn't offer any adjustment for the curvature, so this may be a starting point.

[image]

If you don't want to install git to get the addons, you can get a snapshot of the contrib repo [from here](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender-addons-contrib.git/snapshot/HEAD.tar.gz).

Comment: This looks like it could be useful, though yes, it may not do what i want. The blocks need to have rounded faces because they are actually tamped sandbags. Thanks for the info, i'll try it. :)