# Edging/Bricks around plane?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, edges

What is the best way to put bricks around a plane? I would manually place them but I'd like a more dynamic way as it's not just going to be straight all the time.

The thing I've tried doing is duplicating the edges I want the bricks to follow and doing an array and curve modifier to them, and it works somewhat... It doesn't follow the curve exactly and it overflows a little bit and then I tend to have issues like this...

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure if it would be better to try and fix the issues here or just try something else? I'm starting to think it would be easier just to manually place them at this point...

Comment: "It doesn't follow the curve exactly": it should, make sure that both the 2 origins are at the same place for example

Comment: if you show us your blend file we could help you better...

Comment: Check out this answer - may be possible to take the edges of your geometry, convert to curve, and use this method.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28765/a-reliable-way-to-make-a-brick-tower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your topology, but if think ahead, to include the width of your kerb in the road-plane, (and the style suits you), you can take an approach like this:

[image]

- <kbd>I</kbd> Inset your road, and invert the selection to select the rim

[image]

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate the rim, and <kbd>P</kbd> separate it to a new object.
- You may have to make a few adjustments to the cross-cuts in the rim, but if you were planning for this method, it shouldn't be too much loop-cutting..
- When you have got your edges where you want them, give the kerb an *Edge Split* modifier, followed by *Solidify* and  *Bevel* modifiers.

[image]

Quite a common method, for generating bricks, tiles, shingles, etc.

Comment: This is really good idea! Thank you very much!