# how to move geometry without streching it?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to move this geometry but if i do it will strech, i wonder if theres any modiffier or something that will make me move it just the way "it is" without streching

[image]

Comment: you should use a curve for the thread (or a cylinder arrayed along a curve) and array a plane along the same curve, then parent your pearl to the plane, select your plane, in the Object panel > Instancing, click on Faces

Comment: @moonboots thank you so much! i will try this now ♥♥♥

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28768/110840 - should be able to do the same thing